# Combine ember.js and asp.net webapi JSON formats

Tags: json, ember.js, asp.net-web-api

I am currently building a web app with ember.js and webapi 3.
Currently I am facing the problem that webapi sends a JSON result (of an array of DTOs) which doesn't get understood by ember because it is missing a root element.

I didn't got far with the solutions on the web, which mostly just pointed to a template project for VS.

Has someone a simple and understandable solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're talking about Ember-Data.

web-api sends back json in whatever format the object is, so if you're sending back a list/array it's going to return an array of objects.  If you have control of the controller then just modify what it's returning.

```
return new { foos = new List<string>() };
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to alter my REST API. If this is the best solution. Is there a hook in the WebAPI serializer where I can do that for all actions?

Comment: If you don't want to alter the api, then the best solution is to create a client side serializer.  Check out this document, it talks about serializers per models https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

Comment: If I wanted to add a root node to all collections webapi returns, is there a common place I can hook in that logic?

Comment: `use extractSingle and extractArray when the top-level of your payload is organized differently than Ember Data expects`.  The big difference between `extractSingle` and `extractArray` is one expects a singular model such as `foo: {}` whereas the other expects `foos: [{},{},...]`

Comment: I see, so those are the two "entry"-points of ember data...looks understandable.